Trying to identify an old novel adaptation, please help
The movie I'm looking for is a novel adaptation, one of the books was a part of my assigned reading list. We watched parts of the movie and I remember that it was about a family, man and woman who have somehow decided to make up their own fictional daughter and live as if she's a real person, but at the end they have guests at home and they decide to tell them the truth. I think the father says something like she died in a car crash, in an attempt to kill the illusion and tried to persuade the mother that they have to stop pretending, but she was very mad at him for "killing" their daughter. The mother has a nervous breakdown because she finally had to come to terms with reality and accept the truth that their daughter does not exist.
Heart-wrenching and kind of scary to me personally. Not everything might be 100% correct but I believe this is what happens. It's in color, not black and white, if that matters.

Hey! Thanks for posting. Do you not remember the name of the book at all, either (since you presumably read it, given that it was assigned reading)? Knowing what book the movie was based on would be super helpful. It would also be super helpful if you had any idea:

When the movie came out (even just a ballpark estimate - e.g. if you have an idea of what decade the movie's from).
What country/area the movie was from and/or what language it was in.

If this helped you think of any new info, you can add it to your question by clicking "edit"! Thanks.

Are you sure it was in color and not colorized from an original black and white?

Sounds like "Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf?", movie from 1966, based on the play of the same title by Edward Albee.

George and Martha are a middle aged married couple, whose charged relationship is defined by vitriolic verbal battles, which underlies what seems like an emotional dependence upon each other. This verbal abuse is fueled by an excessive consumption of alcohol. George being an associate History professor in a New Carthage university where Martha's father is the President adds an extra dimension to their relationship. Late one Saturday evening after a faculty mixer, Martha invites Nick and Honey, an ambitious young Biology professor new to the university and his mousy wife, over for a nightcap. As the evening progresses, Nick and Honey, plied with more alcohol, get caught up in George and Martha's games of needing to hurt each other and everyone around them. The ultimate abuse comes in the form of talk of George and Martha's unseen sixteen year old son, whose birthday is the following day...

Instead of a daughter, the couple has an imaginary son, who died in car accident.

George accuses Martha of engaging in destructive and abusive behavior with the boy, who frequently ran away to escape her attention. George then announces he has received a telegram with bad news—the boy was killed in the afternoon on a country road when he swerved to avoid hitting a porcupine and crashed into a tree.
As Martha argues with George that he "can't do this" and begs him not to "kill" their son, Nick suddenly realizes the truth—Martha and George had never been able to have a baby, for reasons that are unexplained. Instead, their game together is to imagine that they have a son and invent situations and stories of him. By declaring their son dead, accordingly, George has "killed" him.


Thank you, IvanaMNE! That's the one. I was sure they had a daughter, but it seems I was wrong, haha. I can watch it in its entirety now! :D

@Raze - I was sure it was in color, but it seems my memory failed me... It was really in black and white. Maybe I got it confused with some of the other movies we watched during the course.

@ghostdog - Yep, it was part of the reading list, but I didn't read it because I had individuals authors assigned, and the whole list had 100 books. But they're all classics and now I feel bad for not reading all of them. I guess it's never too late to do so. :D
